# Changing Locations Based on Last Entry

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make an inventory app using Google Sheets and I cannot seem to solve a problem I have with items changing locations. I have all my form entries going to a single sheet and was able to use an array table to show all the quantities of the in and out values. The problem is that a lot of my material changes location so I need to be able to look at all the responses and find the last entry for a specific material and return the location.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

I apologize if this has been asked already, I did a search and couldn't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Could you provide sample of your data?

Comment: Here is a link to my demo sheet. The form responses is collecting the data and the inventory is a pivot table showing it. I cannot get it to return the last location for each item though. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UFyVhUwH_OFx1Bo_4lcXeoAZYIjvn1ISlj2nuK6kURs/edit#gid=1316120291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you sample sheet just had dates in the timestamp. If your real data also includes the time, you could use the following query on the inventory sheet. Enter in E2 and copy it down.

```
=query('Form Responses 1'!A:E,"SELECT E WHERE B contains" & "'" & Inventory!A2 & "' order by A desc limit 1",0)
```

Comment: Ed, thank you that appears to be what I needed! I really appreciate it.